# Implementing the back button on bb10

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10

I have one navigation pane and I disabled the back button in the main.qml, however I want to display the back button again to some part of the app. How do i implement this? here's my cpp

```
pane = qml->createRootObject<NavigationPane>();

    // Set created root object as the application scene
    app->setScene(pane);

    qml->setContextProperty("cppObj", this);

}

void ApplicationUI::onLoginClicked() {
    // create scene document from buttonclicked.qml asset
    // set parent to created document to ensure it exists for the whole application lifetime
    QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///projects.qml").parent(this);
    qml->setContextProperty("cppObj", this);
    Page* root = qml->createRootObject<Page>();
    pane->push(root);
}

void ApplicationUI::onAddClicked() {
    // create scene document from buttonclicked.qml asset
    // set parent to created document to ensure it exists for the whole application lifetime
    QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///addprojects.qml").parent(this);
    Page* root = qml->createRootObject<Page>();
    pane->push(root);
}
```

and here's my main where I disabled the back button

```
NavigationPane {
    backButtonsVisible: false }
```

How do i make the back button active to some section of the app?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the following code:

StartPage

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

NavigationPane {
    id: navPane

    Page {
        Container {
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill
            layout: DockLayout {
            }
            Button {
                horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
                verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                text: "Next Page"
                onClicked: {
                    var nextPage = page.createObject();
                    navPane.push(nextPage);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    attachedObjects: [
        ComponentDefinition {
            id: page
            source: "NextPage.qml"
        }
    ]
}
```

NextPage:

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

Page {
    // disables backButton (not peeking)
    paneProperties: NavigationPaneProperties {
            backButton: ActionItem {
            enabled: false
        }
    }

    // [0]
    Container {
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill
        layout: DockLayout {
        }
        Button {
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
            text: "Prev page"
            onClicked: {
                var page = navPane.pop();
                if (page)
                    page.destroy();
            }
        }
    } // [0]

    // hides navigation bar
    onCreationCompleted: {
        navPane.backButtonsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

Then you can completely disable `backButton` with this code in `NextPage.qml`

```
onCreationCompleted: {
    navPane.backButtonsVisible = false;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to have navigation pane visible but just Back Button disabled, use following in the same `NextPage.qml` file:

```
paneProperties: NavigationPaneProperties {
    backButton: ActionItem {
        enabled: false
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget about `peekEnabled` property. Using peek BB10 feature user can move between sibling pages using sliding finger movement not touching any buttons on the screen.

It could be done in similar way:

```
onCreationCompleted: {
    navPane.peekEnabled = false;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: By this back button is just disabled, I want to not show the back button on the specific page

Comment: so do you want to have a navigation pane but without back button at all then? otherwise 
``onCreationCompleted: {
    navPane.backButtonsVisible = false;
}``
will hide back button on any page you're after

Comment: I set the navpane to main, if i use the navPane.backButtonsVisible = false it hides all the back button in the navpane pages, i just want to hide the back button on one of the page.

Comment: Use ``navPane.backButtonsVisible = true;`` on all other pages where you want to have it visible or, alternatively, plug into ``onPopTransitionEnded`` or ``onPushTransitionEnded`` signals in navigation pane and have this job done here only. It's up to you, really